# How to remove duplicates on a column basis in Pig

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

will anyone help me to remove the old records from my csv file and keep recent record using Pig.

EX: input

Key1    sta DATE

XXXXX   P38 17-10-2017

XXXXX   P38 12-10-2017

YYYYY   P38 11-10-2017

YYYYY   P38 23-09-2017

YYYYY   P38 14-09-2017

ZZZZZ   P38 25-10-2017

ZZZZZ   P38 10-10-2017

My expected output would be

Key1    sta DATE

XXXXX   P38 17-10-2017

YYYYY   P38 11-10-2017

ZZZZZ   P38 25-10-2017

And header also be included in an out put.

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested foreach can be used for this case,

```
A = LOAD '....' AS (
B =
    FOREACH (GROUP A BY key1) {
        orderd = ORDER A BY date DESC;
        ltsrow = LIMIT orderd 1;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(ltsrow);
    };
STORE B into 'output' using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
```

To learn about nested foreach, look at this,
https://shrikantbang.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/apache-pig-group-by-nested-foreach-join-example/
https://community.mapr.com/thread/22034-apache-pig-nested-foreach-explaination

and on saving output with schema,
https://hadoopified.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/pigstorage-options-schema-and-source-tagging/

Comment: Dear Suresh, this is perfectly working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below will work for you.

```
a = load 'pig.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (name:chararray,code:chararray,x1:chararray);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE name,code,ToDate(x1,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS x1;
grpd = GROUP b BY name;
firstrecords = FOREACH grpd {
        sorted = order b by x1 desc;
        toprecord    = limit sorted 1;
        generate group,FLATTEN(toprecord);
};
dump firstrecords;
```